# How can filter subdocuments in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a User model where I am calling aggregate and finding users according to provided distance and location.

```
const user = await User.aggregate(
            [{"$match":
                        {location:{$geoWithin: { $centerSphere: [ [ -79.7624177, 43.7315479 ], 100/6378.1 ] } },
                    }}
            ])
```

when calling aggregate on my model I got this result:

```
[ 
{ _id: 5fd8de1d3bcb9c8c903c78b5,
    books: 5fd8e038ad6c8b8f20d2c88f,
    email: 'user14@test.com',
    firstName: 'user14',
    password:
     '$2b$10$DSfPujGGoqHMNs6ssbPYuur7s3Jl7lldC6G6C7alVdbA5fioI9dE.',
    location:
     { coordinates: [Array],
       _id: 5fd8de1d3bcb9c8c903c78b6,
       type: 'Point' },
    __v: 1 },
  { _id: 5fd8de4d3bcb9c8c903c78b7,
    books: 5fd8e091ad6c8b8f20d2c896,
    email: 'user13@test.com',
    firstName: 'user13',
    password:
     '$2b$10$Je6vICzPUt7U.qCV0DMcT.zS4k.x5rzbg4cTpfBkxZ9/bL8w8u4eq',
    location:
     { coordinates: [Array],
       _id: 5fd8de4d3bcb9c8c903c78b8,
       type: 'Point' },
    __v: 2 },
  { _id: 5fd8de4d3bcb9c8c903c78b7,
    books: 5fd8e094ad6c8b8f20d2c89b,
    email: 'user13@test.com',
    firstName: 'user13',
    password:
     '$2b$10$Je6vICzPUt7U.qCV0DMcT.zS4k.x5rzbg4cTpfBkxZ9/bL8w8u4eq',
    location:
     { coordinates: [Array],
       _id: 5fd8de4d3bcb9c8c903c78b8,
       type: 'Point' },
    __v: 2 },
  { _id: 5fd8ded13bcb9c8c903c78bb,
    books: 5fd8dfc6ad6c8b8f20d2c888,
    email: 'user11@test.com',
    firstName: 'user11',
    password:
     '$2b$10$qq5WC9oodV82B1UllvWdZ.lZrRMkFsQrxBGn.8mY/uHTcSc4.thrq',
    location:
     { coordinates: [Array],
       _id: 5fd8ded13bcb9c8c903c78bc,
       type: 'Point' },
    __v: 1 } ]
```

I want to filter this also with **books** properties how can I achieve it?

I tried with $and

```
{books:{$eleMatch:{"title":  {$eq: "JavaScript: The Definitive Guide" }}}}
```

But I am getting an empty array.

Comment: Could you please improve the formatting on the query and the output?

Comment: done! is it readable?

Comment: Much better, thanks!